# How to find the value of capacitor in a compensated attenuator?

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor, pole-compensation

I am learning about compensated attenuators and I do not understand the way that the book suggests to create CF.

Is there a link or an  image about the way that the book recommends to find the value of CF needed to compensate the circuit?

[image]

[image]

Is the following image is what the book is talking about?
[image]

Comment: Finding the value is easy. just set both RC products the same. However, you'll usually find Cf is only a few pF (if that much) : the text suggests how to use the PCB's own parasitic capacitance for the job; trimming it with a scalpel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite simple: -

$$R_F\cdot C_F = R_G\cdot C_G$$

Transpose to find \$C_F\$. The business about cutting tracks is about forming the correct value capacitance. Or, there are other methods such as using a resistive divider on the output and then feeding back with a 0.5 pF capacitor. Choose the resistive divider to "adjust" the value of capacitor. Many ways to skin this cat: -

[image]

It's not quite the same circuit as the op's but, it's near enough to explain what I mean. Notice that CF in the above diagram is a feedback capacitor but, its effectiveness is reduced by the potential divider formed by RA and RB. In effect, you can modify this resistor divider to "modulate" the CF value and give you what you need without taking to scraping off copper tracks. [Image source](https://www.planetanalog.com/using-pspice-to-analyze-amplifier-loop-stability-part-2-of-2/#).

Comment: could you plz explain a little bit more about 'The business about cutting tracks' ? I cannot imagine how it is done. I know that the goal is finding the CF value but I want to understand the procedure the book is talking about

Comment: The capacitor is over-sized at the beginning and you monitor the output signal as you trim bits of the copper off. The copper forms a capacitor with the ground-plane. You trim until you get just about the correct output transient response. It's a pretty daft way of doing this sort of thing these days I will add.

Comment: I do not understand why CF should be formed with the ground-plane.  Ain't it supposed to be formed between two pins of Rf?

Comment: Oops yes, I meant to say that it **also** forms a capacitor with the ground plane. The copper forms a capacitor with the feedback resistor @SeAlGhz

Comment: I edited my question could you plz take a look at the image at the end of my question? is that what I am going to do?

Comment: @SeAlGhz that's pretty much what the instructions say but there is a flaw in those instructions. You start with too-much feedback capacitance and, too-much means that the output signal is over-damped i.e. it may not show any transient overshoot behaviour with some op-amps but, on the other hand it may cause ringing on other op-amps. This is why I do not recommend this technique. There are better methods.

Comment: I got the point. thanks for your kind response.

Comment: This is a good article that explains that too-much capacitance will not cause overshoot (unlike what your instructions say): http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/Appnotes/01494A.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The capacitance described in OP is very small indeed - less than one picofarad.
An alternative \$C_F\$ capacitor is shown below, as a short twisted-pair of blk-red insulated wire-wrap wire. It's initial length was more than 1 cm. It is wired in parallel with the visible 3.3M \$ R_F\$ feedback resistor.

The initial length is estimated so that too much capacitance causes high-frequency roll-off. The two wires are equally snipped (in one stroke) to lessen capacitance, and re-tested, watching for the approach to "peaking" at the high-frequency end. In this case, with a 3.3M feedback resistor, wire length reduced to about 4mm.
[image: photodiode transimpedance amplifier compensated with feedback capacitor]

In this case, ground plane sits underneath the 3.3M feedback resistor. If the required capacitor is small enough, this bit of copper could be attached to the end of the resistor that also ties to opamp output (instead of ground), thus forming capacitance to the adjacent resistor body.

While \$C_F\$ can be roughly calculated, it is often small enough that stray capacitance influences its optimum value. A prototype must be built, and tested with a pulsed optical source, then Cf tweaked to achieve desired bandwidth.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your answer is what I have been looking for. I actually do not understand  where the red and black wire are tied to. and why there is a twisted wire? why there is not only a single wire? are these twisted wires acting like capacitor planes? and about this sentence '''his bit of copper could be attached to the end of the resistor that also ties to opamp output (instead of ground), thus forming capacitance to the adjacent resistor body.''' you mean that one side of the plane is not connected to anywhere? and it is just placed in the vicinity of another pin of resistor?

Comment: The red & Black wires comprise \$C_F\$, in parallel with \$R_F\$. They are twisted to make them mechanically more stable, so that capacitance *between them* doesn't change. If the required \$C_F\$ was small enough, the blk wire (going to opamp inverting input) might be left off...capacitance between red wire & resistor body remains. However, mechanical stability would be poor: replacing red wire with a PCB copper trace would be better, *but only if \$C_F\$ is really tiny*.

Comment: Only if parts count or cost is of upmost importance should you use the capacitance-to-resistor approach. Andy's excellent answer describes a more-sane approach to overshoot-compensating network involving \$C_F\$, Andy's approach is also more repeatable.